# Convergence of Power Series to Its Cesaro Sum sentence in Fourier proof

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, cesaro-summable

Well, I am learning about Fourier sum, and I encountered Cesaro sum in the proof of convergent uniformly of Fourier sum,
I know that Fejér sentence says that:
$\|f(x) - \sigma_n(f))\| < \epsilon .$ for all x.

then I know I should use Cesaro sentence that says:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n(f)}=L,$ than Cesaro sum also $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sigma_n(f)}=L$

but then I see that I should prove the convergent between Cesaro sum and the partial sum

$\|s_n(f) - \sigma_n(f))\| < \dfrac 1{N+1}\sum_{k=-N}^N|n||\hat{f}(n)| < \epsilon$

which add the condition with Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma that $f$ should be continuously differentiable
to have Fourier series converge uniformly.

which confuse me because I thought Cesaro sentence already promise me that
$\|s_n(f) - \sigma_n(f))\| < \epsilon$ , so why should I check when the sums converge if I have the sentence that's promise me that, or I misunderstood the sentence.

Comment: Convergence in Cesaro sense does not imply convergence of the original partial sum sequence. You need those extra conditions if you want convergence of the original partial sum sequence.

Comment: so there is a rule for the cesaro sentence that i need here? or this is enough $\|s_n(f) - \sigma_n(f))\| < \dfrac 1{N+1}\sum_{k=-N}^N|n||\hat{f}(n)| < \epsilon$ , i saw cesaro sentence mentioned in fourier convergence proof so i am confuse if i need it or not